# Ajax Request handle at time in browser and how to remove ajax request after its complete from network tab

Tags: ajax, browser, request, call

how much ajax requests can be handled in browser network tab? if i send 100k ajax requests, can browser network tab send 100k ajax request or not or can i clear my previous ajax request from network tab after its done?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
 $.ajax({ 
   type:"POST",  
    url: form.attr('action'), 
    data:form.serialize(), 
    dataType: "json",  
    success: function(response){       
    if(response.msgtype=="success"|| response.msgtype=="fail")  {          
         clearconsole(); // this will clear out the console
 }  
});
```

---

or this in Firefox

```
if (! ('console' in window) || !('firebug' in console)) {
    var names = ['log', 'debug', 'info', 'warn', 'error', 'assert', 'dir', 'dirxml', 'group', 'groupEnd', 'time', 'timeEnd', 'count', 'trace', 'profile', 'profileEnd'];
    window.console = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) window.console[names[i]] = function() {};
}
```